# Python: When I have a if statement and a print assigned to 3 integers, and I type one higher, it gives both that, and the correct print

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if i'm just being dumb, but I am new to python. When I execute this, and type a number higher than  7, it gives me 5, 6, and 7's answer, and the > 7 print. It tells me, "I hope it crosses the border into awesome", and then "That's awesome". 
P.S I am using Python 3

```
print ('What is your name?')
LeName = input ()
print (' How are you, ' + LeName + '?')
print ('On a scale of one to ten, what would you rate your day so far?')
mood = int (input())
if mood <4:
    print ('That\'s horrible, I hope it gets better.')
if mood == '5' '6' or '7':
    print('Hope it crosses the border into awesome! :)')
if mood > 7:
    print('That\'s awesome!')
print ()
```

About 1/2 hour after posting I thought about it and changed if mood == '5' '6' of '7', to if mood >= and mood < 8. But i was still curious as to why this was happening. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: @MattBall -- perhaps surprisingly, it is valid, but "That's not even valid code!" was my first gut instinct as well.

Comment: As a side note, you can use different types of quotes to avoid all those ugly escape sequences: e.g.  `print("That's awesome!")`

Comment: Also think about using elif statements instead of the subsequent ifs.  Often times they are the useful way to prevent multiple matches.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This statement:

```
if mood == '5' '6' or '7':
```

is being parsed as:

```
if (mood == '56') or '7':
```

which is really just `if '7'` or `if True` since the *type* of `mood` is `int` while the type of `'56'` is `str`.

What's happening is that python is applying automatic string concatenation to `'5' '6'` to turn it into `'56'`.  It's not equal to `mood` since `mood` is an `int` and `int` and `str` types never compare equal. So, you have `if False or '7'`.  but `'7'` is a true-like value, so that block will always execute.  What you probably want is something more like:

```
if mood < 4:
   ...
elif 5 <= mood <= 7:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

Where I've used [operator chaining](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) to do what I think you were attempting.

Comment: Correct answer.  But it would probably be helpful to add how to do this correctly such as `if mood in ('5', '6', '7')`... et al.

Comment: @sberry -- I as getting to that.  Ultimately that fails as well because mood will never be in there (it's an `int`).  This thing is better done via operator chaining anyway ...

Comment: Right you are about `int`.  I guess I should have read the OP's code.  And I agree on the operator chaining which is why I included `et al` in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

easy with tuple as:

```
if mood in (5, 6, 7):
```

Comment: In this case, you might be better off with a `set`:  `if mood in {5,6,7}:` but really, I think operator chaining is the cleanest way to do this as I've demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: @mgilson, for just 3 items, the tuple is probably faster than a set - unless you are preconstructing the set.

Comment: @gnibbler -- I've timed them once or twice before and I think the turnover time is right around 3 elements.  I'm timing it again and it appears to be the case.  (`tuple` wins most of the time if the element is the first one, `set` wins otherwise).  Of course, In my test I'm not using a *set literal*.  In this case, python will probably cache the tuple literal but not the set literal which will give tuple the edge when using literals.

Comment: But I suppose for problems where we're getting user input, timing probably doesn't matter anyway (I just thought it would be good to point out that a `set` is *usually* a better data structure for testing containment)